# Can I merge/modify notifications in notification tray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, notifications

Actually, I want to create notification like WhatsApp providing in Android. Every time when a new notification comes, I like to merge it in previous one, like this one:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Format changed for readability

Answer (score 0):

It is not posible in iOS, It's different concept for notification on android but in iOS it's not possible to group notifications for a specific app by yourself.